# Implement a grid on iPad with UITableView... question

Tags: ios, ios4, ipad

I need to build a grid such as this one on iPad: http://showyou.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/showyou_ipad_grid_overtheshoulder.jpg

So far, I know I can use UITableView and I'm adding a subView to cell: rowView.

Now... since I've just started working with iOS and I don't want to break MVC model. Can I just a define a new view rowView and add it to UITableViewCell ?

What if I need to define interaction in the view ? Such as pushing a new UIViewController on screen after tapping ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to help you properly on this, so I'll try first by answering your questions:

You can add subviews to tableviewcells during runtime.

If you need interactions you can implement the touchesXXX methods in your custom views you can also add targets to any UIControl descendant such as a UIButton, which may be part of your custom view.

**EDIT**

You can use [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) since iOS 3.2 and add those to UIViews such as

- [UITapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer)
- [UIPinchGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
- [UIRotationGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIRotateGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIRotationGestureRecognizer)
- [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
- [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPanGestureRecognizer)
- [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer)

so you don't have to handle the actions in your views but instead in your view controllers.

Comment: So all touches methods are handled by View. Is this correct or should the controllers handle them ? (I'm trying to have a good design). Also, how can I move a subview to right so they don't overlap ? thanks

Comment: @Patrick updated my answer. What do you mean by: "move a subview"? You can set the position of a view by manipulating its center or frame property.

Comment: It actually works only if I assign the recognizer to the parent View, (the table row), if I assign to the children I don't tapping method is not invoked.

Comment: Do your views and subviews have the `userInteractionEnabled` property set to true?